# Error on runtime: stringWithCString is deprecated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, runtime

I used this code:

```
const char *propName = property_getName(property);

NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:propName];
```

The compiler gave me "stringWithCString is deprecated". so, what is the correct method?

Comment: looks like i need to do NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:propName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper method is `+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]`